# How to get sampleRate for microphone?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-audio-api

I need get sampleRate for microphone in JS.
I tried those ways:

```
//Example 1
var context = new window.AudioContext();
var sampleRate = context.sampleRate;

//Example 2
var audioTimer = 0;
var sampleRate = 0;
recorder.onaudioprocess = function() {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    if (audioTimer) {
        sampleRate = (1000 * 2048) / (time - audioTimer);  //2048 - buffer size
    }
    audioTimer = time;
}
```

But I got sampleRate value for speakers only, not for microphone

Comment: You didn't try to get the microphone

Comment: This is the question "How to get sampleRate for microphone?"

Comment: yes, but you didn't try at all

Comment: Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the MediaDevices API to enumerate devices and examine the audio input.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices)

However, I'd point out this won't help in Web Audio - Web Audio will always resample the input to the output device sample rate (and clock) when you use attach a stream to the audio graph.  In the future, you should be able to create a context at a different sample rate, and then it will (mostly) work; there's no provision for locking to the actual input clock, though.